# C++ delete min element in binary tree

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I have the following function for deleting the min element:

```
int BinaryTree::delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node){

   while(node->left != NULL){
     node = node->left;
   }

   if(node == root){
     return 1;
   }

   delete node;
   node = NULL;
   return 0;
}
```

I always pass a pointer to the root node to this function.  I've tried this and a few variations of it, but it always seems to delete the the wrong thing or not delete anything at all.  Any ideas why?

Here is a compilable example:

```
#ifndef _TREE_H_
#define _TREE_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TreeNode {
  int val;
  char *str;
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
};

class BinaryTree {
  public:

 BinaryTree();
 ~BinaryTree();

 int insert_node(unsigned int val, char *str);
 TreeNode *find_min();
 int delete_min();
 void print();

 private:

 int insert_node_helper(TreeNode *&node, unsigned int val, char *str);
 int delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node);
 void print_helper(TreeNode *node);

 TreeNode *root;  
};

#endif

BinaryTree::BinaryTree(){
  this->root = NULL;
}


BinaryTree::~BinaryTree(){
}

int BinaryTree::insert_node(unsigned int val, char *str){
  return insert_node_helper(this->root, val, str);
}

int BinaryTree::insert_node_helper(TreeNode *&node, unsigned int val, char *str){

  if(node == NULL){
    node = new TreeNode;
    node->val = val;
    node->str = strdup(str);
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    if(node != NULL){
      return 0;
    }else{
      puts("inserted null node");
      return 1;
   }
 }else if(val <= node->val){
   return insert_node_helper(node->left, val, str);
 }else if(val > node->val){
   return insert_node_helper(node->right, val, str);
 }

 return 1;
}

void BinaryTree::print(){
  print_helper(this->root);
}


void BinaryTree::print_helper(TreeNode *node){

    if(node != NULL){
      print_helper(node->right);
      printf("%d occurrences of \"%s\"\n", node->val, node->str);
      print_helper(node->left);
    }

}

TreeNode *BinaryTree::find_min(){
  TreeNode *temp = this->root;
  while(temp->left != NULL){
    temp = temp->left;
  }
  return temp;
}

int BinaryTree::delete_min(){
   return delete_min_helper(root);
}

int BinaryTree::delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node){

   while(node->left != NULL){
     node = node->left;
   }

  if(node == root){
    puts("attempted to delete root");
    return 1;
  }

  delete node;
  node = NULL;
  return 0;
}

#include <time.h>

int main(){

  BinaryTree bt;

  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     bt.insert_node(rand() % 20, "test");
  }

  bt.print();
  printf("min val = %d\n", bt.find_min()->val);
  puts("#################################");
  bt.delete_min();
  bt.print();
  printf("min val = %d\n", bt.find_min()->val);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're setting your node pointer to NULL immediately BEFORE you delete it (which does nothing now but solidify with a vengeance your memory leak).? Also note. **your using a reference**. You're changing the inbound pointer with each leap down a level in the tree. the last one being setting it to null, then deleting nothing. Finally, your algorithm does nothing to account for a tree that is right-weighted exclusively and has no left. The proper action there is to delete the root node, but you better find the right replacement before doing so.

Comment: off topic: why do you have `*&` and why does your function returns `0` for no reason and why do you delete with `node = NULL` as well as `delete node`?

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the comment.  Very helpful!  I added a check for the root node.  In this case it deletes everything except the root.

Comment: @user2052561: You're still using a reference. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

You are taking a reference to a pointer as argument (`TreeNode *&node`), and then modify it. So if you pass the root of your tree to this method, you will eventually set the root to `NULL`.

Additionally this actually deletes absolutely nothing, because you call delete after setting the pointer to NULL, and `delete` called on a null-pointer does nothing.

*Update after edit of original post:*

I assume `root` is a member of BinaryTree. It would be easier to help you if you posted a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/).

You're still taking root as a reference. Thus `node == root` will always be true, and you'll never reach your `delete` statement. So actually you're not deleting anything, but you're changing your root to be the left-most child node.

Try changing your method signature to

```
int BinaryTree::delete_min_helper(TreeNode *node){
```

that is, without the ampersand (`&`).

*After edit:*

Ok, now I've run your program, and found your second problem. In the line

```
node = NULL;
```

You're changing the value of a local pointer, not of the `left`-pointer in the parent node. This means than when you traverse the tree the next time, you will access a pointer to the memory you just deleted. That triggers undefined behaviour. To get around this you should set the `left`-pointer of your parent node to 0 when you delete your leaf-node.

Comment: Okay.  I was thinking that for the delete to be persistent I needed to use a reference or pointer to pointer, but your suggestion seems to work.  Thank you!

Comment: @user2052561 "...seems to work" Hmm. For your own sake, try to *understand* why your assumptions were wrong and why this answer is right, rather than being happy with the fact that *it seems to work*.

Comment: Thank guys. This still doesn't do what it's supposed to.  Per request, I made the SSCCE.